# cmake выполнение комнд bash в командах cmake

Tags: bash, cmake

Стоит задача: собрать библиотеку и рядом с ней сгенерировать файл в который будет записана дата создания библиотеки в формате "CREATED DD/MM/YY и тд. Пробую разные варианты но пока безуспешно. 
Для начала решил поэкспериментировать со сборкой простого Hello world. Сделал файл Hello.cpp. В файле CMakeLists.txt написал следующие правила:

```
add_executable(hello Hello.cpp )  
add_custom_target(time_step ALL COMMAND echo "CREATED ${date}" > output.txt VERBATIM)
```

Много разных вариантов перепробовал в секции после COMMAMD. ЛУчшее что получилось - это когда использовал COMMAND 2 раза и в одной команде писал в файл строку CREATED, в другой дописывал дату в тот же файл при помощи команды bash >>. Но это дописывание. А мне нужно чтобы писалось за один раз и в одну строку. 
Подскажите как такое можно сделать. Слышал, что вроде можно сделать такое при помощи команды configure_file, но как тоже не очень понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш пример можно сделать так. CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

string(TIMESTAMP TS)
configure_file(output.txt.in output.txt)
```

output.txt.in:

```
CREATED @TS@
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Это сработало. Спасибо за помощь!